# How to simulate a SDN network using VMs (Virtual Box)?

Tags: virtualbox, sdn, mininet

I am trying to simulate a SDN network using VMs as hosts (Virtual Box). Any ideas?

An example: Two VMs running Ubuntu Server and One VM running an Open vSwitch and a controller

The examples that I already found are people using Mininet (but the virtual hosts are too basic for my experiment). I also tried to attach an external host to the Mininet but I think that I made some wrong configuration because the ARP requests do not reach the hosts.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need SDN controller in your topology something likes [ONOS](http://onosproject.org/) or [Ryu](https://osrg.github.io/ryu/) after you finish the setup of SDN controller you can run switches in Open vSwitch and connect them into SDN controller. But for connecting hosts to your virtual network you need something like [vxlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Extensible_LAN) in order to provide layer 2 connectivity.